# Setting profile image from google cloud storage bucket in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage, picasa

I am using google cloud storage for storing profile images for one of the android app which we are developing. I am able to store images to the cloud properly..I want to set the same image to imageview in my application using picasso API.
It is saying Access denied, When I share Image on cloud publicly, it is setting image to Imageview, otherwise not...

How could I give these public share through android application for user to set images using Picasso?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you upload the image you must make sure (assuming you don't want authentication) the ACL is set to publicRead.

The upload in java looks like this:

```
storage.objects()
        .insert(BUCKET_NAME, null, content)
        .setName(fileName)
        .setPredefinedAcl("publicRead")
        .setKey(API_KEY)
        .execute();
```

For setting the ACL manually in the developers console tick the "shared publicly" check box.

The url then looks like this:
http://storage.googleapis.com//

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, But this not provide security leak...I mean anyone can open provided they have the url for the images right? Can we make something like opening for others by giving any specific ACLS?